# System crashes each time i run python command in Terminal, how to get rid of /opt/miniconda3/bin/python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, crash, anaconda, miniconda

please I need your help here!

My system crashes each time i run a python command in terminal. When i run something like `python app.py`, my Mac will crash and bounce, and reset.

In Terminal,
When i run `python -V`, it returns `Python 3.7.6`,
When i run `python3 -V`, it returns `Python 3.8.5`
When i run `which python`, it returns `/opt/miniconda3/bin/python`.

A moment ago, i was trying to build a standalone app, and turned on virtualenv. However no matter how hard i tried, i failed. Then i deleted the virtualenv folder in the app folder.

Perhaps during the development processes, in Visual Studio Code, i accidentally "linked" the virtualenv with the python interpreter 3.7 (/opt/miniconda3/bin/python), which was set as the default python system long ago (i can't even recall when and how). After the virtualenv folder deletion, i remember the interpreter had the word "cached" in the front of the python version. Somehow i turned on and off this and that, and restarted the app, i have get rid of the word "cached". But the system still crashes .

My Mac crashes now every time i run a python command in Terminal. Please help!

i even have tried update `conda update conda`, it says no such directory,
ofcoruse i then tried  update miniconda, same answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove it from your path.

To do so, check for the miniconda3 entry in the file named `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, and `/etc/profile` file and comment out the line:

```
export PATH=/opt/miniconda3/bin:$PATH
```

by preceding it with the `#` character.

Comment: sorry, would you please tell me in details? i don't understand it. like how to check for the miniconda3 entry in both ~/.bashrc?

Comment: `miniconda3`  is added to the `PATH` when you install so you need to remove it from your path. For instance, use `sudo pico ~/.bash_profile` or `sudo touch` and `sudo open` to edit the file. Then, you just comment this follolwing line `export PATH=/opt/miniconda3/bin:$PATH` out. 

HOPE it will work.

Comment: I think you should comment out the whole part of conda initialize

Comment: yes! it works beside the error. now my python -V is "Python 2.7.16". Is this the intended result of your solution? So now i have to run everything with "python3" right?

Comment: Yes! try to run with your python3

Comment: Please capture the screen of `.bash_profile` again. I want to see what happen

Comment: `fi` is missing after if and else. I think you need to take two `fi`s back on the line of 31 and 32. See the first figure you sent to me: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VCgrUgNMJs4ot-lIGlneln4IrkjhPruU/view?usp=sharing. This should work.

Comment: sorry, the problem comes back

Comment: Same problem? How bad is it?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/50310521#50310521 here you go bro!

Comment: According to the error you got when uninstalling anaconda (`PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels`), the mentioned channels are standard servers for people to host packages on. 

`conda-forge` is a community-driven channel where you can find your wanted packages that are not available on the standard channels. 

So, the command I gave you is to try adding the conda-forge channel to your list of channels when you search for packages.